# Pandas: How to explain this .loc behavior on Multi-level column selection and value setting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to select and set value for certain cells of a multi-level column dataframe using [.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). But I'm getting confused by the results and errors I am getting.

For instance,

```
my_list = [['Chicago', 'A', 112, 8],
      ['Philly', 'A', 252, 19],
      ['LA', 'A', 411, 12], 
      ['Chicago', 'B', 112, 8],
      ['Philly', 'B', 252, 19],
      ['LA', 'B', 411, 12]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['City', 'Firm', 'Employee', 'Revenue'], 
                    data=my_list)
df1 = df1.set_index(['City', 'Firm']).unstack()
df1
```

This is will give me a data frame that looks like:

[image: p1]

And here I am trying to select and set values for the two circled cells:

[image: circle]

I am confused whether to use `df1.loc['LA', 'Revenue']` or `df1.loc['LA', ['Revenue']]`. Former gives me the result

```
Firm
A    12
B    12
Name: LA, dtype: int64
```

Compared to latter, which yields

```
         Firm
Revenue  A       12
         B       12
Name: LA, dtype: int64
```

Either method will allow me to set values. But if I sort the column order by the 2nd level, errors will arise.

```
df2 = df1.sort_index(1, 1)
df2
```

Now the data frame looks like this:

[image: new df]

Then if I want to set value with `df2.loc['LA', 'Revenue']` it will not work.

```
df2.loc['LA', 'Revenue'] = 5
```

I got error "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index" while the other method works fine.

```
df2.loc['LA', ['Revenue']] = 2000
df2
```

[image: set]

So I am really curious about the function of bracket in .loc when selecting the multilevel index/column and why sorting a level of the multilevel column could make value setting fail.

For the record, I was getting a different error when I was working on my original data:

```
dfn
```

[image: WORK]

```
dfn.loc['NOK', 'order'] = 5
```

This gives me "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: Because there’s a lot needed at once, I would consider changing your approach to working with the df as is, and using something like `np.where` or `df[df[‘column’] = ‘value’]`. That said, your multi-index approach can be done. I would look at using `df.iat` and `df.at` though.

Comment: @zerecees Thanks for the suggestion. I can certainly work with the dataframe in a different way. It's just that questions arose while I was `.loc` on it and I am curious about the `.loc` behavior in this situation. The documentation doesn't seem to cover this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 la A B for Revenue was 12 12. unstack remove the multiple key index.  set_index to city and firm, use loc to replace your  value, then unstack the dataframe for display 


 my_list = [['Chicago', 'A', 112, 8],
  ['Philly', 'A', 252, 19],
  ['LA', 'A', 411, 12], 
  ['Chicago', 'B', 112, 8],
  ['Philly', 'B', 252, 19],
  ['LA', 'B', 411, 12]]
 
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['City', 'Firm', 'Employee', 'Revenue'], 
                data=my_list)
 df1 = df1.set_index(['City', 'Firm'])

 df1.loc[('LA','B'),'Revenue']=14
 df1.loc[('LA','A'),'Revenue']=13

  df1 = df1.unstack()
  print(df1)

  output
     Employee      Revenue    
   Firm           A    B       A   B
   City                             
   Chicago      112  112       8   8
   LA           411  411      13  14
   Philly       252  252      19  19
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This seems to work. But I still want to know the difference between `df.loc[:, 'ColumnA']` and `df.loc[:, ['ColumnA']]`. Just what does the extra pair of brackets do?

Comment: The extra brackets make it a list. You output one column name but you could add more column names